# How to calculate pointers in a binary tree with the van Emde Boas layout

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, cache-oblivious

I'd like to implement a cache-oblivious binary tree that is stored in an array using the van Emde Boas layout, using implicit pointers. All items in the tree are 32-bit integers and the tree will get fairly big, so storing the pointers would mean at least 3x more data.

The problem is that I can't think of any non-iterative way to calculate pointers to the left and right children, given a node index (I can track any information while traversing the tree). Many papers/lectures refer to such trees with implicit pointers, but I haven't seen an algorithm to calculate the pointers. Is there an efficient way to do it?

Comment: Do you need to calculate it from an index?  It seems to me that you just need to calculate a particular child node from a current node.  If you are willing to be aware of the current level, keep a stack of offsets on the path to the current node, and have an array of all of the offsets at different levels, you should be able to do it.  I don't know how much overhead tracking those stacks will add, it may not be worthwhile.

Comment: You are right, I don't need to calculate it from arbitrary index. I'm not sure I understand the idea with an array to all offsets? Do you mean offsets to all items on a specific level?

Comment: Have you checked [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.76.762&rep=rep1&type=pdf) out? They give how to lay out a tree using the van Emde Boas layout in section 2.1.

Answer (score 6):

Bob Copeland has a very good implementation of [van Emde Boas trees at GitHub](https://github.com/bcopeland/em_misc/blob/master/vebtree.c).  He uses implicit pointers and calculates the pointers by first calculating the breadth-first pointer, after which vEB pointers are a simple conditional.